# pow() operator vs extended euclidan algorithm

Tags: python, pow

I'm constructing a library that generates public keys and private keys for RSA encrypting.

I got two big primes, p, q, that is 1024 bits. I want to compute the inverse of the public key e = 2**16 + 1 in mod (p-1)(q-1).

Python allows me to simply write `pow(e,-1,(p-1)(q-1)` to get the inverse. I could also get it through extended euclidan algorithm.

My question is, with such big primes, (and the fact that e and (p-1)(q-1) is coprime), what method is most efficent? How do I find the timecomplexity for the operator pow in python?

[I can't find it in the library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=pow#pow)

Comment: The time complexity might be moot if you have to implement an alternative in Python. Doubtful it would effectively be faster than the built-in version. How big will your primes get? You'd be better off profiling alternatives against the sorts of inputs you'd expect than relying on time complexity.

Comment: Anyway, I'd be surprised if the the implementation doesn't already just use the extended euclidian algorithm

Comment: Yea, that is my thought also. I can set the primes as big as I want, but I'm thinking of 512 bits.